# Are there any simple and effective Open Source Java database-backed queue libraries?

Tags: java, queue, libraries, jobs

I have a few different apps which need robust database-backed job/task queues, and so far I've had trouble identifying any promising candidates. I'd love some suggestions!

BTW, by database-backed I intend something which persists job data and status to a JDBC DB for reliability purposes.

Oh, I'm specifically looking for a library. I'm aware of systems such as ActiveMQ and JMS-based systems. But I need my apps to remain self-contained and not turn into entire platforms. (I've also always had some trouble making the conceptual leap to modeling jobs/tasks as messages.)

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you take another look at ActiveMQ. While it is by default a standalone application, you can also embed it in your application, making it "self-contained". I've done this using ActiveMQ's [Spring support](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) but you can also do it programmatically by simply instantiating the correct classes in your app. ActiveMQ is lightweight and offers several persistence mechanisms.

Regarding whether there is a dissonance with thinking of "messages" as "jobs", I guess it depends on what you mean by "job". If I hand you a piece of paper that says "mow the lawn" and you think of that as a job, then messages can be jobs. If instead you don't have a job until you actually start mowing the lawn, then they are not.

Perhaps you may want to look at [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/), which uses a [job-based domain model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#domain). It too is embeddable and has persistence, retry, etc. built in.

Comment: Thanks!

Do you have any thoughts on what I perceive of the dissonance involved in thinking of jobs as "messages"? Am I just being too rigid/literal?

Comment: @Avi: I've added two paragraphs to my answer.